# How to insert image blob in openpyxl

Tags: python, flask, openpyxl

In my web app I'am using openpyxl to create or modify excels and there's a part of my web that i need to insert image with a blob or base64 ?, I dont see anything related in how to inserting image in openpyxl except in a method where i need to pass a relative or absolute path of the image. i don't want to save the image first to my project directory before using it for the excel.

```
@route(data_mgt, rule='/elevation-values-calculation/download-error-ratio', methods=['POST'])
def download_error_ratio():

    payl = payload()

    survey_id = payl.get('survey_id', {})
    project_id = payl.get('project_id', {})

    image = request.files['image'] #return blob

    image_string = base64.b64encode(image.read()) #return base64 string

    base64_string = "data:{content_type};base64,{img_string}".format(
        content_type=image.content_type, 
        img_string=image_string.decode()
    )

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(base64_string) #error need to pass absolute or realte image path
    img.anchor = 'A1'
    ws.add_image(image)
```

Comment: what's the issue ... you seem to be doing it right. I think you mean `ws.add_image(img)` instead of `ws.add_image(image)`.

Comment: Hi @SulemanElahi `openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(path)` can only pass absolute or relative path of the image. Is there any method of **openpyxl** where i can pass blob or base64 image ?

_dont want to save the image first in my environment_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a file from `request.files` it is wrapped in a [`FileStorage`](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage), which can be used in the [`openpyxl.drawing.image.Image`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.drawing.image.html) directly as it accepts either a filename or an open file.

The following minimal app works to receive images and put them at "A1".

```py
from flask import Flask, request
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/add_image", methods=["POST"])
def handle_add_image():

    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active

    img = Image(request.files["image"])
    ws.add_image(img, "A1")

    wb.save("/tmp/74981726.xlsx")
    return b"OK"
```

Tested with cURL:

```bash
curl -i -X POST -F image=@Downloads/5x1aqu4dtuny.png http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_image
```

Comment: I overlook my problem and I tested your answer and it works!, Thank you :)